# MSI script to check sql server 2000 PE for a db name and not rerun db install script

Tags: sql, database, scripting, windows-installer

I am seeking help on building a script that will allow my msi installer to check for an exsisting db or exsisting user on the local server of sql server 2000 Personal Edition, during the pre install, the script needs to return the sql response and not run/resintall the sql scripts if the db name or db user is on the server already.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute `master..sp_helpdb`

This will give you a list of the databases that you have access to on the server.